# Lenovo X131e Chromebook Xfce4 USB Read and Write Problem

Tags: xfce, usb-drive, chromebook, filemanager, crouton

It won't allow me to change my 8 GB Yoda USB-drive into read & write in the permission tab so that I can install Steam games there.

I changed it then half a second later it changed it back to read only.

I think it's trolling me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install games with *root* access account?

Also it depends on how you have formated the USB drive.. often they are **FAT32** and if so, it may cause this problem.

If you format your USB to **extX** then you and simply use `chmod` and `chown` to set permission and owner for you USB.